# Score updates every frame on raycast hit, not only once

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need to make somehow, that when a player runs through raycast, the score value updates by one. But instead, it updates every frame.

I tried to fix it with boolean check, but anyway, it's work as before.

Where did I make a mistake?

Here's the code:

```
public class ScoreBehavior : MonoBehaviour{

public delegate void ScoreUpOnPass();

public static event ScoreUpOnPass onRayHit;

private int score = 0;

private bool hitOnce = false;

void Start()
{
}

void Update()
{
    RaycastHit hit;
    Ray checkRay = new Ray(transform.position, Vector3.down);
    
    
    if(Physics.Raycast(checkRay, out hit))
    {
        if (hit.collider.tag == "Player" && !hitOnce)
        {
            hitOnce = true;
            Debug.Log(score); // updates every frame
            onRayHit?.Invoke();
        }
        else
        {
            hitOnce = false;
        }
    }
    
}
```

}

Comment: Do you have other objects with colliders in the scene? I would think its getting reset when the hit.collider.tag is not Player

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to use `OnTriggerEnter()`. Raycasting is just not a correct choice of instrument in this case.
Add a collider at the score point, set it to `isTrigger = true` and use `OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)` to check who has entered the trigger area. It will be triggered only once for each object entering the area, and will be triggered again if the object leaves the area and then goes back, so it's the best instrument for this task.

Comment: Raycast in my situation would be better on my opinion, but I got it to work around with collider. Thank for the idea :)

Comment: @LongCat I fixed the raycast to work as you had intended. Was not all there when I initially posted the snippet. Ermiq set me straight.

Answer (score 1):

I would try moving your if check a bit in case it hits nothing or hits an object that is not tagged player.

```
void Update()
{
    RaycastHit hit;
    Ray checkRay = new Ray(transform.position, Vector3.down);
    
    if (Physics.Raycast(checkRay, out hit))
    {
        if (hit.collider.tag == "Player" && !hitOnce)
        {
            hitOnce = true;
            Debug.Log(score); // updates every frame
            onRayHit?.Invoke();
        }
    }
    else if (hitOnce)
    {
        hitOnce = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: It won't change anything... Raycast hits, is player? Yes. `hitOnce` is false. Score up, set  `hitOnce = true`. Next frame: is player? Yes. `hitOnce` is false, set it to true. Next frame: player, false, score up, set to true... So, the score will be still raised. It just will happen every second frame rather than every frame.

Comment: @Ermiq Sorry was half asleep when I typed it up. Try this.